# How can I prevent the hacking of my wired and wireless networks by tools like feedingbottle?

Tags: wireless, networking, security, password

I am network administrator and I am always worried about network security as I know people use different techniques of hacking to penetrate wireless and wired networks. Recently I came to   about software called Feedingbottle which can hack WEP on finger tips; you don't even have to know anything about networking and hacking as its just a simple GUI.

I am interested in knowing how this works and what we can do to avoid this.  I'm also interested in knowing if there are any other tools available that can do this.

I know about Aircrack, but in order to use it you should have some knowledge about how it works.  I know hacking WPA is really difficult and although most default passwords giving by ISP's are sometimes hackable, but if you change the password and use WPA or WPA2 it is nearly unhackable if the password is good.

Is this correct?  If not, how can I avoid having my passwords hacked?

Comment: This is off topic, as it is a general network security question, and better suited to plain stack exchange or similar.

Comment: Are you really specifically interested in what tools are available *for Ubuntu?* It's hard to imagine a scenario where a network administrator would be reasonably concerned *only* with attackers who limit themselves to using Ubuntu. This seems too broad to be on-topic here. I recommend asking about this on [Security.SE](http://security.stackexchange.com). Please note that there are legitimate uses for these tools, and questions both about using them and evading them are on-topic here, but only if they specifically relate to Ubuntu.

Comment: ahan @EliahKagan i asked here becasue the tools which are more powerful are linux/ubuntu based so maybe i thought there are similar softwares for ubuntu aswell

Comment: and i didn't mentioned that our network is ubuntu based our servers and clients are ubuntu based

Comment: yes i want to know specifically for ubuntu

Comment: @YousafEhsan What OS your machines are running might not be as germane as you may think. Users virtually always have to have root privileges to run such tools, and with root privileges, they can also install another operating system, or run a virtual machine to perform reconnaissance and launch attacks. My understanding is that Feedingbottle simply a frontend for aircrack-ng, is available for Ubuntu, and `.deb` packages are provided, though I have not confirmed this and I don't know of a source for a *trusted* `.deb` package. Are you sure *unskilled* attackers are where your focus should be?

Comment: yes i am sure unskilled attackers and i know my cousin he havea very little knowledge of computer and and he even dont know what is linux but he hacked alot of weps using this tool and sometime wpa's thats why i was really concerned about this.

Comment: I'm afraid this does look too broad.  As @EliahKagan mentioned, it would be better on [security.se].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is on topic, enough.

There are no security tools that i know to make WEP safe. The way aircrack works when collecting IVs is part of the protocol. Thus the change to WPA(2).

The authentication of wireless clients is a side question to what OS. (unless you consider unix dd-wrt and tomato to be somehow relevant) The point is there is not a platform program to secure your wireless protocols.

You might ask how can one be secure even with an uninvited guest on the network, but I think that is a different question.

Comment: You might want to mention something about the security value of long, random keys, for WPA(2).